# How can I make the Google Eddystone url notification to make a sound when detected

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, eddystone, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I am using eddystone beacons to transmit my business url. How can I make the url notification received to alert thru sound on the users device? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Understand that **Eddystone-URL beacon advertisements don't automatically do anything on a user's phone unless they have an app installed to detect them.**

Chrome for iOS and Android (installed on many newer Android devices, but very few iOS devices) will automatically detect Eddystone-URL advertisements and display a notification from Chrome if the user has opted-in.  However, no sound is played.  **Bottom line:  on a phone without a custom app, detecting an Eddystone-URL will not cause a sound to play.**

**If you build a custom app and get it installed on users' devices, you can certainly make it play a sound** on Android devices when the beacon is detected.  On iOS devices, you could also display a local notification on the device that will play a sound, but only if the user has the volume turned up on the device, does not have do not disturb on, and has opted-in to receiving notifications from the app.

Comment: If you want to go the custom app route, you can just change this line in the Physical Web prototype app:
https://github.com/google/physical-web/blob/master/android/PhysicalWeb/app/src/main/java/org/physical_web/physicalweb/UrlDeviceDiscoveryService.java#L83

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answear